# Pattern for consolidating API calls while maintaining loose coupling?

Tags: reactjs, api, single-page-application

Single-page apps often make several API calls on first load. Something like a dashboard might: load user information, load main content, load sidebar content, etc.
Letting individual components worry about making these requests is easy but increases load times since you have *n* components making *n* requests.

One approach is to consolidate under a single API endpoint all of the calls made by any one page. So now the dashboard page no longer makes *n* calls to *n* different endpoints but 1 call to the newly-introduced `/dashboard` endpoint.
This solution comes at the cost of couples serverside logic with client logic, which seems like a bad idea.

Another approach would be to limit this coupling to the client by consolidating all API calls to a single component which then could batch up all the queries, wait for the response, decompose it into its parts, and then distribute those results to the corresponding components. This approach seems better than the above, though there's still coupling.

*Question*: is there a well-established pattern (or a popular library) for addressing this problem? I imagine that every large application runs into this problem at some point, yet I can't find any information on the subject.

Comment: So you want to replace n small requests from several components which would render as soon as their respective requests have resolved, with a single big request that blocks the entire page load and rendering untill all the data for every puny little component has been loaded? Do I get this right? Check this talk out: https://youtu.be/X-kA8B2QzjY?t=448 I've linked the timestamp before the part relevant to this question begins, but you might want to view it from the start for better context.

Comment: Well, GraphQL is a "pattern" to send custom API calls where you can define and compose on the client side what data you want to get and how it should be aggregated. and https://www.apollographql.com/ is a pretty popular library to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how large your application is but since you mentioned"every large application runs into this problem at some point" I think [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) is what you need.

**GraphQL** was developed internally by Facebook in 2012 before being publicly released in 2015. It basically provides a new approach to developing web APIs and has been contrasted with REST and other web service architectures. GraphQL supports read, write (they call it mutation), and subscribe to changes to data - realtime updates.

A little bit of history on why Facebook built GraphQL: In 2012, Facebook was working on their mobile application for Android and iOS. They had to make changes in their existing REST services to make it working for their mobile platforms as well considering data fetching on mobile devices with low network bandwidth. In order to resolve this issue, they started to work on GraphQL so they could still use their existing services for mobile platform as well.

There are so many advantages using GraphQL but one of them is what you are exactly looking for: **Get many API’s response in single request**

Also fo the front-end if you are using React, you can use **[Relay](https://relay.dev/)** The production-ready GraphQL client for React by Facebook. Also there is another client GraphQL framework called [**Apollo**](https://www.apollographql.com/)

---

Here is just an example how the query is sent and how you will get the response based on requested query

### request:

```
{
    orders {
        id
        productsList {
            product {
                name
                price
            }
            quantity
        }
        totalAmount
    }
    header {
      id
      isReadOnly
      ... 
    }
    .....
}
```

**Response**:

```
{
    "data": {
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "productsList": [
                    {
                        "product": {
                            "name": "productName",
                            "price": 20.55
                        },
                        "quantity": 100
                    }
                ],
                "totalAmount": 80
            }
        ]
        "header": {
              "id": 1, 
               "isReadOnly": false,
                ...
        }
    }
}
```